# Pass CommandLine Arguments to buildScript

Tags: gradle

I have a below task

```
task showLog1 <<{
def grgit = org.ajoberstar.grgit.Grgit.open(dir: '')
def log = grgit.log {
    range '$tag1','$tag2'
}
}
```

Now I was using my tag names after the range but I want to pass this through Command Line. I have gone through few links like http://mrhaki.blogspot.in/2010/10/gradle-goodness-pass-command-line.html and I am passing from cli  using -p like below:

```
gradlew showLog1 -ptag1=tag_one -ptag2=tag_two
```

But this doesn't give me the log. Anything that I am missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its working, I need to write my task like below:
    **build.gradle**
    def grgit = org.ajoberstar.grgit.Grgit.open(dir: "")
    def log = grgit.log {
       range "$tag1","$tag2"
    }

Then I need to execute it like this :
    **Command Line**
    gradlew showLog1 -Ptag1=tag_one -project-prop tag2=tag_two

Answer (score 0):

Try a capital "P".

Like so: -Ptag1=tag_one -Ptag2=tag_two

Comment: Tried. It doesn't work. Gives error "No commit found for revision string: $tag2".

Comment: Also tried gradlew showLog1 -Ptag1=tag_one -project-prop tag2=tag_two,(as in the ex in that link)  same error it gives

Answer (score 0):

If you pass your vars via -P option as format -PvarName=xxx. varName became a property of you project object in buildScript

```
if (project.hasProperty('varName')) { //check varName is set or not
      println "varName set to:" + varName; //use the varName directly.
}
```